# What is the difference between the Python type method and the type function on a Maya Transform Node?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

Question in title

Example code:

```
>>> j.type()
u'joint'
>>> type(j)
<class 'pymel.core.nodetypes.Joint'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this simple example. You are trying to compare two different things - `Joint` class method `type` and python built-in function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#type) - they have same names, that all:

```
class Joint():
    def type(self):
        return u'joint'

>>> j = Joint()
>>> j.type()
'joint'
>>> type(j)
<class '__main__.Joint'>
```

Comment: @shfury u means unicode. What system and python version you are using?

Comment: @shfury at first i tried to run this example in python2 actually, that because u is present in this line - `return u'joint'`. But when i realized that you are on python3 (by built-in `type` return value), i ran my code in python 3 and post results. I think you are using windows because on linux in python3 there is no u in front of printed string value(result of calling `j.type()` in my example), all strings in python 3 is unicode by default...